# override public function initialize() error in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, flexbuilder

i want to know what i should put befor .mx_internal

```
override public function initialize() : void
    {
        var target:DialogButtons;
        var watcherSetupUtilClass:Object;
        .mx_internal::setDocumentDescriptor(_documentDescriptor_);
        var bindings:* = _DialogButtons_bindingsSetup();
        var watchers:Array;
        target;
        if (_watcherSetupUtil == null)
        {
            watcherSetupUtilClass = getDefinitionByName("_components_DialogButtonsWatcherSetupUtil");
            var obj1:* = watcherSetupUtilClass;
            obj1.watcherSetupUtilClass["init"](null);
        }
        _watcherSetupUtil.setup(this, function (param1:String)
        {
            return target[param1];
        }// end function
        , bindings, watchers);
        var i:uint;
        while (i < bindings.length)
        {

            Binding(bindings[i]).execute();
            i = (i + 1);
        }
        mx_internal::_bindings = mx_internal::_bindings.concat(bindings);
        mx_internal::_watchers = mx_internal::_watchers.concat(watchers);
        super.initialize();
        return;
    }// end function
```

Answer (score 0):

`mx_internal` should be without dot.

Comment: @ Timofei as i google mx_internal then i come to know ,in everyprogram,there is something they have added to mx_internal  like super.mx_internal

Comment: @Siddhesh Jadhav why do you need to use super here? Try to remove dot

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to reference the mx_internal namespace every time you access it.  You can just import it into the class.  Use statements like this:

```
import mx.core.mx_internal;
use namespace mx_internal;
```

Then re-write your code like this:

```
override public function initialize() : void
    {
        var target:DialogButtons;
        var watcherSetupUtilClass:Object;
// line commented to snow the mx_internal less code
//        .mx_internal::setDocumentDescriptor(_documentDescriptor_);
        setDocumentDescriptor(_documentDescriptor_);
        var bindings:* = _DialogButtons_bindingsSetup();
        var watchers:Array;
        target;
        if (_watcherSetupUtil == null)
        {
            watcherSetupUtilClass = getDefinitionByName("_components_DialogButtonsWatcherSetupUtil");
            var obj1:* = watcherSetupUtilClass;
            obj1.watcherSetupUtilClass["init"](null);
        }
        _watcherSetupUtil.setup(this, function (param1:String)
        {
            return target[param1];
        }// end function
        , bindings, watchers);
        var i:uint;
        while (i < bindings.length)
        {

            Binding(bindings[i]).execute();
            i = (i + 1);
        }
// lines commented to snow the mx_internal less code
//        mx_internal::_bindings = mx_internal::_bindings.concat(bindings);
 //       mx_internal::_watchers = mx_internal::_watchers.concat(watchers);
        _bindings = _bindings.concat(bindings);
        _watchers = _watchers.concat(watchers);
        super.initialize();
        return;
    }// end function
```

Comment: hi friend i tried it and i am geting error at my variable saying "the type was not found or was not compile-time constant:DialogButton"                                          this is var i am getting error                                      public var _DialogButtons_DialogButton1:DialogButton;

Comment: @Siddhesh Jadhav That class comes from the original code you posted.  I assume that DialogButton is a custom class you created.Make sure it is imported.