# could not resolve <custom:DialogTitle> to component implementation error in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, flex4, flexbuilder

I am getting the following error ...

```
could not resolve <custom:DialogTitle> to component implementation
```

What does this mean and how can I resolve it?

Comment: It is what it says it is. To use `DialogTitle` component from `custom` namespace you must import this namespace into your mxml file. You do that by adding `xmlns:custom="path.to.package.of.your.component.*"` as one of the attributes of root tag of your mxml file.

Comment: Show us your code.  @2dh is correct; and I believe I said a similar thing when you asked as part of this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916421/override-public-function-initialize-error-in-flex

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to extend a flex component that is close to what you would like to do and @2DH is right.

For example do something like "DialogTitle extends TitleWindow"